# JCombobox, getSelectedItem() out of ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have one JCombobox with Strings and I want to select one. I followed the instructions on [documetary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItemListener%28java.awt.event.ItemListener%29) and created the Array like suggested there. I need the String to pass it further to another class. If I want to pass over `s`, it wont work, because it's declared inside `itemStateChanged`. If I try to set `x = s`, won't work too, because `s` is defined in an enclosing type. So my question is basically, how do I get the `String s` out?

```
    String[] strategies = {"Select Strategy", "FastestAppFirst", "SmallestAppFirst", "BestFitFirst"};

    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(strategies);
    contentPane.add(comboBox, "2, 2, fill, default");

    String x="";

    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            String s = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    });
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your `x` or `s` variable as field of class, and it will be work. Or use somthing like this:

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        String s = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //passToAnotherClassMethod(s);
    }
});
```

[read tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for `JComboBox`

Answer (score 2):

Define a field of class and store the selection in the field. Or define a method in the class you need the selection and call the method in the `itemStateChanged()`.

```
targetClass.setSelection(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
```